# Вложенные классы

Tags: java

Зачем нужны вложенные (`inner`) классы? Хотелось бы увидеть какой-нибудь практический пример.
В Хорстмане есть объяснения, но они какие-то не слишком понятные. Примеры в его книге даны на основе слушателей (`listener`) и потоков.
Хотелось бы услышать, применяете ли Вы внутренние классы? И как Вы определяете, нужны ли они?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как по большей части сосредоточились на внутренних анонимных или непубличных классах, то приведу пример использования внутренних классов, когда те должны стать частью публичного API.

Для примера можно взять [Map.Entry](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) из Java SDK. По плану разработчиков, единственным путем для получения объекта `Entry` должен являться вызов итератора на представлении этой мапы (это представление обычно получается через `entrySet()`). Кроме того, объекты `Entry` невалидны вне контекста их использования при итерации по мапе - практически любые модификации мапы приводят `Entry` в негодность. Так что вполне логично реализовать `Entry` как внутренний интерфейс для `Map`. Такими же соображениями можно руководствоваться при конструировании своих классов.

В моей личной практике чаще всего внутренними публичными классами становятся перечисления. Вот есть, например, класс со свойством типа какого-нибудь `enum`. Если предполагается, что другим классам он точно не нужен, то можно включить его внутрь использующего его класса, чтоб другим разработчикам неповадно было его использовать не по делу.

Answer (score 4):

На самом деле в Хортсмане хорошо описано зачем они нужны.

Так как в Java нельзя создать указатель на функцию(делегат) и передавать его как параметр или вобщем как-то обрабатывать,как в С++ или замыкания как например в любом динамическом языке как Python, Groovy, где обработка событий сведется к созданию анониимной функции или в современном как Scala, то для поддержки и реализации событийной модели применяется вот такой изврат: интерфейсы и внутренние классы, а порой еще и анонимные класы, которые их реализуют.

Как-то сумбурно вышло, но думаю суть донес.

Ждем JDK 8, когда наконец-то появятся замыкания. Мне вот только непонятно самому одно: пошли путем простоты и не делали изначально язык сложным, то теперь же постепенно его усложняют, те же замыкания появятся. Хотя думаю в реализации это будет очередная хренотень как и с генериками. Понятно, что так проще основной массе, которая хорошо знает основы и затем может "доизучать плюшки", но все же неоднозначно как-то!

Пример:
У меня есть виджет списка ListView:

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.exerc_list);
//обрабатываем событие ява-путем так:
lv.setOnItemClickListener( new ListItemLisener() );
class ListItemLisener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long id) {
        String checkedExName = (String)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(pos);
        for(ExerciseData item:exercises){
            if( checkedExName.equals(item.name) ) {
                checkedExId = item._id;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
//либо так, используя анонимный внутренний класс:
lv.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long id) {
        String checkedExName = (String)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(pos);
        for(ExerciseData item:exercises){
            if( checkedExName.equals(item.name) ) {
                checkedExId = item._id;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
//но в современном языке было бы например так:
lv.setOnItemClickListener( (AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long id)-> { String checkedExName = (String)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(pos);
        for(ExerciseData item:exercises){
            if( checkedExName.equals(item.name) ) {
                checkedExId = item._id;
                break;
            }
        }} );
```

Comment: А что в новом не нравится ? Непривычно конечно, но разумно. 

Говорим: вызывай при наступлении события вот такую функцию, код прилагается, компили по месту.

Так скоро и "адреса" структур данных появятся. Адреса в кавычках осознанно, реализацию представляйте в меру своей фантазии.

Comment: Что Вы имеете ввиду под "новом"? Не понял вопроса.

Comment: /но в современном языке было бы например так: 


вот это

Comment: Так наоборот мне такая запись нравится больше:) Она короче и нагляднее. Только помню слух про Java 8, что там все равно будет создаваться объект при такой записи и class-файл для него.

Comment: И мне нравится. И "адресов", чтобы программы понятнее были не хватает.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, к вложенным классам нету доступа из вне - это в некоторых случаях, делается для защиты.
В случае с листенерами - так удобней, ты конечно можешь это все выносить в отдельный класс и даже так надо, если у тебя там достаточно сложная логика.
Иногда, так удобней делать небольшие объекты, например, для отладки.