# Для чего в java нужны вложенные классы?

Tags: java, классы, вложенные-классы

Для чего в java нужны вложенные классы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Для начала нужно понимать разницу между нестатическими вложенными классами (non static nested classes) и статическими вложенными классами (static nested classes).*

### Нестатические вложенные классы (non static nested classes)

*Они же - внутренние классы.*

**Где применяется?**

Там где вы описываете структуру будущего объекта, который имеет не только состояние и поведение, но и имеет какие-то дополнительные (составные) части. Без которых сам объект не существовал бы.

Например, машина. Смысл от нее теряется, если она стоит во дворе на кирпичах, а колеса от нее лежат в гараже, а вам нужно сесть и поехать. В таком случае вам придется потратить время, чтобы взять машину, взять домкрат, взять колеса и проделать все действия по их установке.

**Как применяется?**

Внутренний класс имеет доступ через методы ко всем полям и методам внешнего класса и может ссылаться к ним напрямую. Но внешний класс может обращаться к методам и полям внутреннего только по ссылке. Выглядит это так:

```
public class Outer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer outer = new Outer();
        outer.print();
    }

    private int outer_x = 100;

    void print() {
        Inner inner = new Inner();
        inner.innerMethod();
    }

    class Inner {
        public void innerMethod() {
            System.out.println(outer_x);
        }
    }
}
```

Или чтобы из метода `main` вызвать напрямую метод внутреннего класса, мы может сделать это так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Outer outer = new Outer();

    Outer.Inner inner = outer.new Inner();

    inner.print();
}
```

Внутренний класс так же можно определять внутри методов и циклов.

---

### Статические вложенные классы (static nested classes)

Первое, что нужно понимать, что вложенные классы в отличии от внутренних помечаются ключевым словом `static`. И чтобы во вложенном классе можно было работать с методами и полями внешнего класса, они тоже должны быть помечены `static`.

**Где применяется?**

Ну, возьмем для примера ситуацию, когда Петя идет в школу с портфелем, а Машенька без, т.е. несет учебники на руках. Тут Петя может сказать - "Слушай, я могу поделиться своим портфелем, ты клади в него свои учебники, все равно мне его нести...". То есть Машенька положит свои учебники в портфель Пети, потому что Петя не жадный, он поделится.

**Как применяется?**

Все обращения к полям и методам внешнего класса и наоборот к полям и методам вложенного класса происходит через класс.

```
public class Outer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer outer = new Outer();
        outer.print();
        // или
        Outer.Inner.innerMethod();
    }

    private static int outer_x = 100;

    public void print() {
        Inner.innerMethod();
    }

    static class Inner {
        private static void innerMethod() {
            System.out.println(Outer.outer_x);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Постараюсь объяснить максимально просто:

В основном в `java` внутренние классы служат нам для того, чтобы привязывать одну сущность к другой. Например: сущность `МАШИНА`, у него есть `руль`, `коробка передач`, `педали`. И зачем создавать публичные классы со всем этим? Просто кинул как внутренний в класс `Машина` и вот лафа.

Так же удобно для применения всяких патернов типа `singleton` и `builder`.

Answer (score -2):

Обычно внутренний класс наследует от класса или реализует интерфейс, а код внутрен­него класса манипулирует объектом внешнего класса, в котором он был создан. Значит, можно сказать, что внутренний класс —это нечто вроде «окна» во внешний класс.

Возникает естественный вопрос: «Если мне нужна ссылка на интерфейс, почему бы внешнему классу не реализовать этот интерфейс?» Ответ здесь таков: «Если это все, что вам нужно, —значит, так и следует поступить». Но что же отличает внутренний класс, реализующий интерфейс, от внешнего класса, реализующего тот же интерфейс? Далеко не всегда удается использовать удобство интерфейсов —иногда приходится работать и с реализацией. Поэтому наиболее веская причина для использования вну­тренних классов формулируется так:

Каждый внутренний класс способен независимо наследовать определенную реализа­цию. Таким образом, внутренний класс не ограничен при наследовании в ситуациях, где внешний класс уже наследует реализацию.

Без способности внутренних классов наследовать (фактически) реализацию более чем одного конкретного или абстрактного класса некоторые задачи планирования и программирования имели бы крайне сложное решение. Поэтому внутренний класс выступает как «довесок» множественного наследования. Интерфейсы берут на себя часть этой задачи, в то время как внутренние классы фактически обеспечивают «мно­жественное наследование реализации». То есть внутренние классы позволяют вам наследовать от нескольких «не-интерфейсов».

Чтобы понять сказанное, рассмотрим ситуацию, где два интерфейса тем или иным способом должны быть реализованы в классе. Вследствие гибкости интерфейсов у вас есть два варианта: одиночный класс или внутренний класс:

```
//: innerclasses/MultiInter*faces.java
// Два способа реализации нескольких интерфейсов
// в одном классе.

interface А {}
interface В {}

class X implements А, В { }

class Y implements А {
  В makeB() {
      // Анонимный внутренний класс:
    return new B() {};
  } 
}

public class Multiinterfaces {
  static void takesA(A а) {}
  static void takesB(B b) {}
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    X x = new X();
    Y у = new Y();
    takesA(x);
    takesA(y);
    takesB(x); 
    takesB(y.makeB());
  }
} ///:~
```

Конечно, выбор того или иного способа организации кода зависит от конкретной ситуации. Впрочем, сама решаемая вами задача должна подсказать, что для нее пред­ почтительно: один отдельный класс или внутренний класс. Но при отсутствии иных ограничений оба подхода, использованные в рассмотренном примере, ничем не от­ личаются с точки зрения реализации. Оба они работают.
   Однако, если вместо интерфейсов у вас имеются конкретные или абстрактные классы, придется «звать на помощь» внутренние классы, если новый класс должен как-то за­ действовать функциональность двух других классов:

```
//: innerclasses/MultiImplementation.java
// При использовании конкретных или абстрактных классов
// внутренние классы предоставляют единственный способ
// провести "множественное наследование реализации".
package innerclasses;

class D {}
abstract class E {}

class Z extends D {
   E makeE() { return new E() {};}
}

public class Multiimplementation {
  static void takesD(D d) {}
  static void takesE(E e) {}
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Z z = new Z();
    takesD(z);
    takesE(z.makeE());
  }
} ///:~
```

Если вам не приходится решать задачу «множественного наследования реализации», скорее всего, вы сможете написать любую программу без использования особенностей внутренних классов. С другой стороны, внутренние классы открывают следующие дополнительные возможности.

1. У внутреннего класса может существовать произвольное количество экземпляров, каждый из которых содержит собственную информацию, не зависящую от состо­яния объекта внешнего класса.
2. Один внешний класс может содержать несколько внутренних классов, которые по-разному реализуют один интерфейс или наследуют от единственного базового класса. Пример такой конструкции вскоре будет рассмотрен.
3. Место создания объекта внутреннего класса не привязано к месту и времени соз­дания объекта внешнего класса.
4. Внутренний класс не создает взаимосвязи классов типа «является тем-то», способной вызвать путаницу; он представляет собой отдельную сущность.

Брюс Эккель "Философия JAVA"

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/44069/%d0%92%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b?rq=1